# Slow loading of parquet files to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet

I have a sample table of 3000 integer columns + `id` one.

There are 256k rows where only the `id` column is filled with numbers, the rest is nulls.

I made an export to parquet format, there were made two files: 678kB (72k rows) and 815kB (184k rows).

The export was made with:

```
COPY INTO '@test/256k_rows_parquet'
FROM x4 
file_format = (type=parquet)
```

Then I made a new table from the first one as:

```
CREATE TABLE x5 AS SELECT * FROM x4 LIMIT 0
```

I loaded the parquet file with

```
COPY INTO x5
(
    id, A_1 [...] A3000
)
FROM
(
    $1:_COL_0, $1:_COL_1 [...] $1:_COL_3000
    FROM
    @test/256k_rows_parquet[...]
)
```

The problem is that the loading the file with 72k rows took 53s while loading the other file with 184k rows took 12 minutes. I'm using the smallest warehouse.

Comment: Are you exporting the data from a system that only exports the data in parquet?  I know this doesn't answer your question, but compressed, delimited files load much faster.

Comment: @MikeWalton Thanks for you comment. I'm exporting that on Snowflake. Exporting a *.csv.gz files with the same data and loading them back takes the same amount of time. While it takes 18s on my computer when loading to postgres :)

Comment: You'd have to share more details on the COPY command, file format, and whether you are splitting the files into smaller chunks (not likely helpful).  A <1 MB file should not take more than a few seconds to load in Snowflake, so more information is likely needed to provide help.

Comment: All this already is in the question. I'm using the copy command written above. The file format is parquet. Loading another 127MB file takes over 30 minutes. The file is not divided into smaller files.

Comment: I was referring to your comment about already testing the csv format and that taking the same amount of time.  It shouldn't, so there is something else going on here that I'd need more information to assist with.

Comment: The csv files are made by exporting the same data from the table (3k columns, 256k rows). I was wondering if the issue is that 3k columns means writing to 3k files when adding a row.

Comment: When you loaded the CSV file, did you specify columns like $1, $2, etc., do any casting or transformation of the data, or was the COPY INTO a straight load?  Having a lot of columns like that won't create more files per column, but it does mean less rows per micro-partition.

Comment: It's just a straight load. `COPY INTO TTT FROM @stage/data.csv.gz`